# fetch data is updating by useState, how to add all of them

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, fetch-api

In my UseEffect, i am having multiple data from my API, because of using useState, my data is updating continuously, but In my case I want all of the, I mean my previous data and next data I want them in one array, I tried to add them using push() method but it doesn't work outside of function, so in this case I want to add my all data in one array and call them outside of function.
How can I fixed this issues, anyone can help me to do that?

Thanks for your trying!

here is my codes in below:

```js
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  roads?.map((id) => {
    fetch(
      `https://www.roads.com/roads/api/auth/roadcontrol/${id}`,
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())

      .then((dataLoc) => setDataLoc([dataLoc.data.latitude]))

      //  .then((data) => {

      //      const latitude = data?.data?.latitude;
      //      const longitude = data?.data?.longitude;
      //      //console.log(data?.data?.id, latitude, longitude);
      //      arr.push([latitude, longitude]);
      //      console.log(arr);
      //  })

      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  });
}, []);

//console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Where does `roads` come from? What about `requestOptions`? Please [edit] your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: for the security purpose i didn't share the real API and request options here, but i am having 40 data in my api and there have different different latitude and longitude. i want all of the in on array and call them outside of fuction.

Comment: by using the push method, i get them in one array but i can't call them outside of function, there is another issues.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want to create a new data structure based off the `dataLoc` state. For that, you can use the [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

First, define some functions to fetch road data. These could be in their own, testable module

```js
const baseUrl = "https://www.roads.com/roads/api/auth/";

const requestOptions = {
  /* ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ */
};

const fetchRoad = async (id) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/roadcontrol/${id}`, requestOptions);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${res.statusText}`);
  }
  return (await res.json()).data; // { id, latitude, longitude }
};

export const fetchRoads = (roads) => Promise.all(roads.map(fetchRoad));
```

Now call setup your initial state, an effect hook to load data and a memo for just the coordinates in your component

```js
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState([]); // initialise as an empty array

const coordinates = useMemo(
  () => dataLoc.map(({ latitude, longitude }) => [latitude, longitude]),
  [dataLoc]
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (roads) {
    fetchRoads(roads).then(setDataLoc).catch(console.error);
  }
}, [roads]); // roads may need to be a dependency, depending on where it comes from
```

Now your coordinates will be in the 2-dimensional `coordinates` array.

Answer (score -1):

this is how you can save all of the data in one array. this ius case one.

```
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  roads?.map((id) => {
    fetch(
      `https://www.roads.com/roads/api/auth/roadcontrol/${id}`,
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())

      .then((data) => setDataLoc([...dataLoc, data.data.latitude])

      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  });
}, []);
```

another case is this using temp array .

```
    const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState();
    
    useEffect(() => {
      roads?.map((id) => {
        fetch(
          `https://www.roads.com/roads/api/auth/roadcontrol/${id}`,
          requestOptions
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
    
          .then((data) => {
let temp_data = [...dataLoc]
temp_data.push(data
setDataLoc(temp_data)
})
    
          .catch((error) => console.error(error));
      });
    }, []);
```